# Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):

Tags: angular

./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.

Error: Failed to initialize Angular compilation - NGCC failed.

./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.

Error: Failed to initialize Angular compilation - NGCC failed.

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

× Failed to compile.

Answer (score 0):

your question is still unclear to me.From your error messages, There was a failure during the module build process using the `@ngtools/webpack` package in an Angular project.

you can do following things

- run `ng clean` to clean the project
- run `ng update @angular/cli` to update angular cli
- run `ng update @angular/core` to update angular core
- run `ngcc --clean` to clear cache
- check version compatibility  of typescript (you can do it by refering your current angular version documentation)
  and all dependent packages used in your project from package.json against angular ivy version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue last week, when changing one small library version.

Even after :

- deleting node_modules
- npm install.

still not working.

The only way to resolve this for me was to

- (optional) Git push
- clone project from git
- npm install

working again.

Perhaps some cache issues.